# Ruby on Rails First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I used the standard Ruby on Rails generate scaffolding. I need help to find out how to move a form from the "New" view to the "Posts" view (Main Page). I keep on getting the error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". Here is my "Posts" view code. It works fine in the "New" view but not the "Posts" view.

Posts View:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
```

New View:

```
<h1>New post</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

Form View:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

   </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :casino %>
    <%= f.text_field :casino %>
  </div>
     </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :City %>
    <%= f.text_field :City %>
  </div>
  </div>
     </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :State %>
    <%= f.text_field :State %>
  </div>
       </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Country %>
    <%= f.text_field :Country %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Game %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Minimum %>
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text, :casino, :City, :State, :Country)
    end
end
```

Comment: What is file name of your `posts view`?

Answer (score 3):

Add this line in index action of PostsController

```
@post = Post.new
```

This should solve your problem :)

***SOLUTION:***

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @post = Post.new

  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I spent 5 hours on my Friday night at a bar trying to figure this out, and you saved me another 5 hours this week. I'll post the solution. Now I think I have a handle on controllers and how they operate. Next step is to figure out a dynamics search I can add to the home page.